# Car hire out of NYC

Tags: car-rentals, new-york-city

I'm looking to find some reasonable car rental rates on 22 November for 4 days.
The cheapest I've found is over 100 USD per day using [kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk/). Is this normal for NYC?. I only need a small car...

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how you're using it, but when I run a Kayak query from the airport, I get about $47 a day.

[I've run the query for your convenience](http://www.kayak.co.uk/cars#JFK-a15830/2011-11-24/2011-11-28).

However, remember that you're looking to pick up on [THANKSGIVING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving).  As this is a public holiday and the start of a long weekend, it's highly likely you'll pay extra charges or that rentals will be in demand as people return home to their families or travel for the long weekend.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i get 106 dollars for the same car that your search gives as you say $47.I am running the query from australia perhaps some sort of geo tagging is happening

Comment: So if you run my search, it shows $47? Or $106? That's just weird if it's $106...

Comment: Anyway, i used your link got the good rate and made the booking .Cheers thanks for your help mark

Comment: No worries, glad to save a fellow traveller some cash!  If you can accept the answer, that'd be fantastic ;)

Comment: when run in UK it defaults to GBP, so the difference might be in exchange rates(from Aus it was Aus dollars, would that explain it).  I have always used thrifty (in us,uk, and Aus) for car rental btw.

Comment: @Nim. AUD is stronger than the USD at the moment, so if that was happening the OP would see the amount drop, not increase.